# How to run a periodic scheduled job without at or cron

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks, cron, at

Scenario: You have a user with *no access to cron* and need to schedule a job  (say an rsync of a directory). The use of `at` is not an option as you don't have a fixed end date.

While I bet there are thousands of ways to accomplish this here's mine:

Comment: normally user has always access to corn - his own cron but obviously not root's

Comment: and another question - why is user taken away user cron access? give it back.

Comment: as well - if its rsync - then rsync can be configured as deamon

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

Open a screen session and create a while loop like that:

```
while : ; do
clear 
echo "$(date : Hey, I'm running this nice stuffz)"
time do_stuff
sleep 1d
```

The key here is the `sleep` command: It accepts much more than just a value in miliseconds. There are format specifiers for second (s), minute(m), hour(h) and day(d). Even more, GNU sleep is not only able to  handle integers as values but 
it can actually handle arbitrary floats (`info '(coreutils) sleep invocation'`).
This means that you could write stuff like:

```
sleep 0.33d  or  sleep 0.5h
```

The  latter is pretty much useless, but so you know ;)

Comment: interesting solution though :D